# What happens if I use vector::begin() instead of std::back_inserter(vector) for output of set_intersection?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, containers, set-intersection

I have been using the highly concise and intuitive C++ syntax for finding the intersection of two sorted `vector`s and putting the result in a third `vector`:

```
vector<bar> a,b,c;
//...
std::set_intersection(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(c));
```

This should set `c` to intersection(`a`,`b`), assuming `a` and `b` are sorted.

But what if I just use `c.begin()` (I thought I saw an example somewhere of this, which is why I did):

```
 std::set_intersection(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end(),
                       c.begin());
```

`set_intersection` expects an `OutputIterator` at that parameter. The standard I believe requires only that `c.begin()` return a `forward iterator`, which I suppose might or might not be an `OutputIterator`.

Anyway, the code with `c.begin()` compiled under clang.

What is guaranteed to happen under the standard? If this compiles, what is likely to happen - that is, when the iterator returned by `c.begin()` is eventually incremented past the end of the vector, and an attempt is made to access the element pointed to, what must/may happen? Can a conforming implementation silently extend the vector in this case, so that `begin()` is in fact an appending `OutputIterator` like `back_inserter` is?

I'm asking this mainly to understand how the standard works with iterators: what's really going on, so I can move beyond copy-and-paste in using the STL.

Comment: Is `Vector` the same as `std::vector`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important requirement for an output iterator is that it be valid and write-able for the range 
`[out, out+`*size of output*`)`.

Passing `c.begin()` will lead to the values being **overwritten** which only works if the container `c` holds enough elements to overwrite. Imagine that `c.begin()` returns a pointer to an array of size 0 - then you'll see the problem when writing `*out++ = 7;`.

`back_inserter` **adds** every assigned value to a `vector` (via `push_back`) and provides a concise way of making the STL-algorithms extend a range - it overloads the operators that are used for iterators appropriately.

Thus

```
 std::set_intersection(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end(),
                       c.begin());
```

invokes undefined behavior once `set_intersection` writes something to its output iterator, that is, when the set intersection of `a` and `b` isn't empty.

> Can a conforming implementation silently extend the vector in this case, so that begin() is in fact an appending `OutputIterator` like `back_inserter` is?

Of course. It's undefined behavior. (This is a humorous approach of telling you that you shouldn't even consider using this, no matter the effects on any implementation.)

Answer (score 13):

`back_inserter` inserts the element in the range by calling `push_back` ( that's why you can't use `back_inserter` with the range which doesn't provide `push_back` operation).

So, *you won't care about* going past the end of the range as `push_back` automatically expands the container. However, that's not the case with insert using `begin()`.

If you are using `begin()`, then you have to make sure that *destination range is big enough* to hold all elements. Failing to do so would instantly transport your code to the realm of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8):

It compiles fine because you get a valid iterator back from the `begin` function, but if the vector is empty then you will get back the `end` iterator, and then continue from there.

It will work ***only*** if the destination vector already contains at least as many elements as you try to add, and then it will actually overwrite those elements and not add new.

And adding elements is just what the [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) iterator does, it returns an iterator that basically does `push_back` on the vector.